# Tensorflow/board: Shape [-1,784] has negative dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Using the code from:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/tensorboard_basic.py

I get errors with the tensorflow placeholder:

> InvalidArgumentError: Shape [-1,784] has negative dimensions
>        [[Node: InputData = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I can run the code once, but after the second run it crashes. Restarting the kernel helps, but this is not a valid fix for me.

This happens also to my own code for input dimension [None,6]. If I uncomment the parts that are necessary for tensorboard (tf scalar, filewriter, summary...), it runs perfectly.

Does anyone know, how to fix that error? I did not found anything helpful.

Greetings

Comment: it seems your data is empty, -1 usually indicate from the last record, so probably your batch_x is empty

Comment: Just for enquiry, are you using Python 2 by any chance?

Comment: I'm using the Python 3.6. I also use not really a batch, my batch is the full data set X_train and Y_train